# Блок try/catch в цикле

Tags: java, циклы, try-catch

Мой код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static int x;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            x = in.nextInt();
        }
        catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Вы точно ввели целое число?");
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                System.out.println("SD");
            } else {
                System.out.println("DS");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Я хочу, чтобы выводилось сообщение "Вы точно ввели целое число?", пока пользователь не введёт целое число. И дальше код продолжил работать. Как мне это сделать?
Пытался зациклить и в catch использовать continue, но безрезультатно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ориентируйтесь на `x == 0`

```
while (x == 0) {
    try {
        x = in.nextInt();
    }
    catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Вы точно ввели целое число?");
    }
}
```

После успешного `nextInt` x станет не 0 и цикл завершится. Если можно будет вводить 0 то этот способ не подойдет. Или укажите изначально x числом, которое вводить нельзя (например отрицательное). Если вводить можно любое число, то поменяйте переменную на `Integer` и проверяйте в условии цикла то что она null. Или создайте цикл так:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        x = in.nextInt();
        break;
    }
    catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Вы точно ввели целое число?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если сделать так, как прошлый комментатор, то в случае эксепшна будет бесконечно писать в консоль "Вы точно ввели целое число?". Решить эту проблему можно таким образом:

```
Scanner in;
        int x;
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Input a number: ");
                in = new Scanner(System.in);
                x = in.nextInt();
                in.close();
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Вы точно ввели целое число?");
            }
        }
```

Comment: _Если сделать так, как прошлый комментатор_, комментариев нет ни под вопросом, ни под ответом. Какого комментатора вы имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true) {
    System.out.printf("Введите: %s ", name);
    try {
        return new Scanner(System.in).nextFloat();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Вы ввели не число! Попробуйте снова.");
    }
}
```

Сам искал решение и практически случайно его нашёл.

Думаю, идея в том, что ошибка сохраняется во внешнем `Scanner in`.

Вот тут нет зацикливания.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Вау это было очень быстро и очень круто o_O. Это алгоритм поправил текст или работа человека?